# How do I make a button to execute and display calculation using variables entered in "Entry" in Python using the tkinter module?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I want to be able to execute the calculation `x + y` when the button `SOLVE` is click.

With how I have done it, I still have to input values for `x` and `y` in the console instead of in the entry block and upon clicking the `SOLVE` button,  it returns :

> "TypeError : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("SOLVE MATH")

def solve_now():
    x= tkinter.Label(window, text="X").pack()
    X = tkinter.Entry(window, text=int(input("Enter X value: 
"))).pack()
    y = tkinter.Label(window, text="Y").pack()
    Y = tkinter.Entry(window, text=int(input("Enter Y value: 
"))).pack()
    ans = X + Y
    tkinter.Label(window, text=ans).pack()

tkinter.Button(window, text="SOLVE", 
command=solve_now).pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This how to get values in `tkinter entry` to do calculation on it.For you to achieve that you have to create `entry widget` then use `get` function to retrieve the value in the entry to do your calculations. Read more about entry widget here  [entry widget](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Using `input` will let you type you value in the console. You are getting `Nonetype error` because you have to position your geometry manager `pack` on the next line after the `entry widget` function.

```
entry1 = Entry(window )
entry1.pack()
```

**Full code**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


def solve_now():
    ans = float(float(entry1.get()) + float(entry2.get()))
    print(ans)
    l3.config(text="Answer : "+str(ans))



window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("SOLVE MATH")

l1 = Label(window, text="Enter Value X")
l1.pack()
entry1 = Entry(window, )
entry1.pack()


l2 = Label(window, text="Enter value Y")
l2.pack()
entry2 = Entry(window)
entry2.pack()

b1 = Button(window, text="SOLVE",
command=solve_now)
b1.pack()


l3 = Label(window)
l3.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly. I am actually trying to write a "bigger" code and I believe it all depends on this one. Thanks again.